# Apache as reverse proxy for multiple destinations and one default destination

Tags: apache-http-server, reverse-proxy

Looking for help for the next Apache's `reverse-proxy` problem.

- have an Apache 2.4 on the localhost:80 (a.a.a.a:80)
- have 3 different web applications

  - one runs on localhost:8000 (a.a.a.a:8000)
  - two others are in another machines - so x.x.x.x:8000 and y.y.y.y:8000
- have some static content (few html pages) on the basic apache:80 's `DocumentRoot`

**Requirements**:

- `appX` (on the x.x.x.x:8000) should be accessed by http://a.a.a.a/appX/
- `appY` (on the y.y.y.y:8000) as http://a.a.a.a/appY/
- existing static pages (from the apache's `DocumentRoot`) should be served as usually by apache
- `defapp` - **everything other** should be proxied to a.a.a.a:8000

It is easy configure the `appX` and `appY` like the next:

```
ProxyPass         /appX/ http://x.x.x.x:8000/
ProxyPassReverse  /appX/ http://x.x.x.x:8000/

ProxyPass         /appY/ http://y.y.y.y:8000/
ProxyPassReverse  /appY/ http://y.y.y.y:8000/
```

The above works OK. So when tried access `http://localhost/appX/` got a response from the `appX` at the `x.x.x.x:8000`.

But have a problem with the `default destinaton` for `everything other`. When tried to add:

```
ProxyPass         /   http://127.0.0.1:8000/
ProxyPassReverse  /   http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

It doesn't works as I hope...

With the above want tell to apache - *everything other what is not `/appX/` or `/appY/` send to `0:8000`.*

And this is unfortunately doesn't works, the `defapp` what runs on `0:8000` got the requests for the `appX` and `appY`, and the requests for the static pages too.

Switching the order of definitions, so

```
#define first the "default destination"
ProxyPass         /   http://127.0.0.1:8000/
ProxyPassReverse  /   http://127.0.0.1:8000/

#and after the appX and appY
ProxyPass         /appX/ http://x.x.x.x:8000/
ProxyPassReverse  /appX/ http://x.x.x.x:8000/
ProxyPass         /appY/ http://y.y.y.y:8000/
ProxyPassReverse  /appY/ http://y.y.y.y:8000/
```

doesn't works either. Everything is proxied to `localhost:8000`.

So, the question is: **is possible configure Apache as a  reverse proxy to handling the above defined requiremens?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your ProxyPass references in a `<VirtualHost>` definition, like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://192.168.111.2/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.111.2/
ServerName hostname.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Create two separate ones with the ServerNames you want, then another without ServerName or the Proxy options defined (just `DocumentRoot`). Put that one last.

More info [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#proxy).

Comment: This works with one local folder without proxy. But how would this work if all folders are on other hosts. Is it possible by using mod_proxy or not? I have this problem.

Comment: @Michael That would be a different question you should ask.

Answer (score 4):

Small impovement to Warren Seine's answer  (missed "app/" in the first RewriteRule (....127.0.0.1/$1 [P....) )

```
RewriteRule         ^/app/(.*) http://127.0.0.1/$1 [P,L]
```

must be

```
RewriteRule         ^/app/(.*) http://127.0.0.1/app/$1 [P,L]
```

So, summing up - In case when all your links are distributed among several hosts (accurately as in your case) try this:

```
ProxyPreserveHost   On
RewriteEngine       On

RewriteRule         ^/appX/(.*) http://x.x.x.x:8000/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse    /appX/      http://x.x.x.x:8000/
RewriteRule         ^/appY/(.*) http://y.y.y.y:8000/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse    /appY/      http://y.y.y.y:8000/
RewriteRule         ^/(.*)      http://127.0.0.1:8000/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse    /           http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

In case when you need to spread your links at the one host (with different ports & BaseURLs)

```
ProxyPreserveHost   On
RewriteEngine       On

RewriteRule         ^/appX/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8001/appX/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse    /appX/      http://127.0.0.1:8001/appX
RewriteRule         ^/appY/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8002/appY/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse    /appY/      http://127.0.0.1:8002/appY/
RewriteRule         ^/(.*)      http://127.0.0.1:8000/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse    /           http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rewrite rules with the `P` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html).

Rewrite rules are more flexible than ProxyPass directives and you can use the `L` flag to stop processing the rule set and avoid the problem you mention (hitting multiple backends).

Here's an example:

```
ProxyPreserveHost   On
RewriteEngine       On

RewriteRule         ^/app/(.*) http://127.0.0.1/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse    /app/ http://127.0.0.1/app

RewriteRule         ^/blog/(.*) http://127.0.0.1/blog/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse    /blog/ http://127.0.0.1/blog

RewriteRule         ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse    / http://127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work.